# generate routes for all entries in table Rails 4 ruby 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a Table called Blog which has 20 entries.
Now i want to create 20 routes fetching title from the Blog table with minimal code or method in routes file.

And i dont want to create it manually.
like whenever i add new entry to table, new route need to be created.

Comment: You probably want one route that uses slugs. Start by googling "rails slug" and go from there.

Comment: get '/:blog_url', to: 'blogs#show' .  blog_url act as slug. but this will take any string and requirest is going to show method of blogs controller. there for i want to generate path for only those url which are already present in the Blog table..and i dont want   get '/blogs/:blog_url', to: 'blogs#show' /blogs/ prefix in url.